# Doing a Sum of Ajax calls

Tags: jquery

I have 3 functions that do an ajax call each and have to be called one after the other. func B() access value of A() and C() access value of B(). http://jsfiddle.net/NYPy6/

I have chained these functions like this:

```
A().then(B).then(C);
```

How can I add another function D() which sums up the result of all three functions using deferred.

Edit: My question is what to write in D() so that I can access values of A + B + C. As shown in the fiddle, it's a json file, so I need to access the json content as **resA.data**, resB.data and so on and finally add resA.data + resB.data in D(). The json file just contains one line data:1 and so on.

Comment: `A().then(B).then(C).then(D);` ?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to chain together (in order) a bunch of functions. Your `D()` function doesn't need to do the sum; you can build the sum as you go along. By using `then()`, the parameter passed to the next function is the result of the previous one in the chain:

```
function A() {
    return {
        data: 1
    };
}

function B(a) {
    return {
        data: a.data + 2
    };
}

function C(b) {
    return {
        data: b.data + 3
    };
}

function D(final) {
    alert('The sum is ' + final.data);
}

var sum = $.Deferred();
sum.then(A).then(B).then(C).done(D);
sum.resolve(); // Alerts "The sum is 6"
```

If you need to pass a parameter to `A()` to begin the chain, that's easy too. Just change the definition of `A()` a bit:

```
function A(init) {
    return {
        data: init
    };
}
```

And then pass a value into the `resolve()` method:

```
sum.resolve(10); // Alerts "The sum is 15"
```

This example is obviously contrived. You will need to replace `A`, `B`, and `C` with your AJAX implementations, e.g.:

```
function A() {
    return $.ajax({ ... });
}
```

Comment: wouldn't n be always "1" here? I want to get a sum of A + B + C and they are independent functions. I fail to understand how will n contain the return values of all these functions

Comment: also it's a json file. So I need access to something like resA.data

Comment: @Thomasmkov: `arguments` is a special keyword that contains an array of the arguments passed to the function. That array will contain the result returned from each of the previously resolved deferred objects. My example is obviously contrived, you will have to adjust it to consume the actual data types and objects returned by your deferreds.

Comment: @Thomasmkov: I was wrong before; I think you need to use `$.when()` here. I edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm this looks fine but when I try it, it returns Cannot read property 'field' of undefined . Also if I had a message to print in A(), B(), C(), I can't know with the use of $when()

Comment: well I see you removed field but it still does not work

Comment: @Thomasmkov: It *does* work: http://jsfiddle.net/NYPy6/2/. I also updated my answer again to reflect the fiddle.

Comment: But my question was I have 3 functions that do an ajax call each and have to be called one after the other. func B() access value of A() and C() access value of B(). Then D() has to sum A() + B() + C().

Comment: @Thomasmkov: I got it now (I hope!): http://jsfiddle.net/NYPy6/3/. Answer udpated to reflect the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
A().then(B).then(C).done(D);
```

Comment: what will I write in D()?

Comment: `D` function should take all arguments from previous function, so `function D(a,b,c) {}`

Comment: @hsz: I thought the same thing; however, when chained like this, `done()` only receives as arguments the results of the previous function (`C()` in this case).